# gdal_merge.py not executing

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-3, gdal-merge

When I type `gdal_merge.py` into Terminal, the output is `-bash: gdal_merge.py: command not found`.

I installed 3.4.0 Madeira [from this link] for macOS 10.13 (https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download), which came with a gdal installer.

I cannot even find the gdal_merge.py file in `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/Current/Programs/` or anywhere else in the gdal framework directory. I looked to see if I could install the `.py` file separately but can't find any installation options on the GDAL website.

Comment: If you have Python installed it could start by `python gdal_merge.py` if all the necessary paths are defined right.

Comment: @user30184 This does not work either, which makes me think that my paths aren't defined correctly. Do you know how I could go about correcting this?